# How to customise the options to the Plug.Parsers JSON decoder?

Tags: elixir, json-deserialization, plug

With [`Plug.Parsers`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html), it is possible to configure the module that is used to parse JSON requests:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:json],
  json_decoder: Jason
```

However, with this syntax [`Jason.decode!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.html#decode/2) is called with an empty `opts` parameter.

How can we provide options to the specified `json_decoder`? For example, I would like to pass the `keys: :atoms` option to `Jason.decode!/2`.

Comment: Please note that dynamically allocating atoms is always a bad thing as they are not garbage collected [https://engineering.klarna.com/monitoring-erlang-atoms-c1d6a741328e](https://engineering.klarna.com/monitoring-erlang-atoms-c1d6a741328e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as the module name, it's possible to pass a `{Module, :function, args}` tuple as the `:json_decoder` argument. This can be used to customise the arguments to the decoder:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:json],
  json_decoder: {Jason, :decode!, [[keys: :atoms]]},
```

This will result in the parser calling `Jason.decode!(data, keys: :atoms)`.

The `[[]]` list-in-a-list syntax is a bit strange, but it's necessary because of the way `Plug.Parsers` handles merging the options. For the same reason, an alternative way is to provide the empty list in the tuple, and include the option directly as an option to `Plug.Parsers`:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:json],
  json_decoder: {Jason, :decode!, []},
  keys: :atoms
```

I prefer the former because the options are better scoped, but the latter could be useful if some parsers share common parameters.

Comment: Should also mention that this is risky, because it would be possible to overload the system with atoms if incoming requests are not controlled somehow.

Comment: I also found out that this specific option (keys: :atoms) does not conform to Plug.Conn's [typespec for params](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#t:params/0), which requires the keys to be binaries, not atoms.